# How to run sample code in Amazon SDK for android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have downloaded aws-android-sdk-1.4.4. I tried to run the sample code provided in sdk. But i am not able run the code. It is not even loading. The eclipse gets stuck and is showing  the following error:

> Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
>   Java heap space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an eclipse problem.  In your eclipse folder, edit eclipse.ini in a text editor.  You'll see a line

-XmsZZZm
-XmxZZZm

The ZZZ is the amount of memory eclipse will use for different purposes.  Increase it until it works.  You'll need to restart eclipse each time you change it.

Comment: I have increased it upto 512m, i think its the maximum limit

Comment: That's not the max, I have mine at 1024.  Possibly there's another cause for that issue, but that's what solved it for me this morning.